# How to prevent css loaded with query being applied to whole page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I am loading content from an external php file and inserting it into a  using query's $.get functionality. The included file contains various css classes. For example, to style hyperlinks. When the file is loaded and the content inserted by jquery, the css styles are not only applied to the new content but also the entire page. To elaborate, I'm loading the content of an html email. Inside the email content is css to style hyperlinks within the email message. The message content is retrieved from the server using a php script and echoed. jQuery gets the content returned from the php script and puts it in the div's inner html with:

```
$.get("file.php",function(data){ $("#div").html(data); });
```

But the css in the email content (returned by file.php) gets applied to the entire page, replacing styles on my own hyperlinks. How can I prevent the new css from being applied to the entire page, and have it only apply to the newly loaded content within the div container without changing the rest of the page's original css?

Comment: Can you make the div `#div` a frame instead?

Comment: Not sure I get it, style tags can only live in the head section, are you loading another head section into your page, or how exactly are these global styles applied ?

Comment: can parse response and only load  body content into your page and use your css to style it's content

Comment: @adeneo since HTML5 it is allowed to put `<style>` elements anywhere in your document, [if scoped](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-preview/the-style-element.html). See my answer for more details on that.

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes - That's great, it's not supported anywhere, and doesn't really work at all, so it still stands that you can't load another file with a head section and style tags into a page that already has a head section, and jQuery would normally filter out such elements during an ajax call, so I don't really see how the OP is adding styles from an ajax request ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 possible solutions.

1) Try using an iframe and just populate its content with the CSS and HTML.

2) Maybe try and add a `<div>` wrapper that has an ID then just prepend the ID to all of the definitions in the CSS?

EX:

```
<div id="emailWrapper">
 ... Email Content/CSS ...
</div>
```

CSS (Before):

```
.someClass {
  .. attributes ..
}
```

CSS (After):

```
#emailWrapper .someClass {
  .. attributes ..
}
```

Comment: i don't like frames because i think they're a messy ui to work with and style attractively, but i think it's going to be the simplest and, more importantly, most reliable and compatible solution. funny the things the brain thinks of and doesn't think of ...

Answer (score 0):

This is currently impossible in a cross-browser compatible fashion without using an `iframe`. In the future you will be able to use scoped styles ([but not yet](http://caniuse.com/style-scoped)) like this:

```
<div>
  <style scoped>
    p { color:green; }
  </style>
  <p>This text is green</p>
</div>
<p>This text is the default color</p>
```

It will also be possible (in an entirely different way) with [Shadow DOM and templates](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/shadowdom/), but again, [not yet](http://caniuse.com/shadowdom) and [not yet](http://caniuse.com/template).